# Can I use multiple position:fixed in same page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to use fixed contents for multiple containers, Can you please help me to achieve this.

Here is the sample code.

I need each container should have its own fixed element and that should not scroll beyond the container.

```css
#cf1, #cf2{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

#content2, #content1{
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  position:absoulte;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <div id="content1">
     Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
    <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
    <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
    <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
    <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
     1) Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
    <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
    <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
    <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
    <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
    
    <div id="cf1">
      test
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content2">
     1) Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
    <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
    <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
    <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
    <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
     1) Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
    <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
    <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
    <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
    <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
    
    <div id="cf2">
      test22222
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#cf1, #cf2{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

#content2, #content1{
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
   <div class="container">
      <div id="content1">
         Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
        <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
        <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
        <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
        <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
         1) Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
        <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
        <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
        <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
        <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
      </div>
      <div id="cf1">
        test
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container"> 
    <div id="content2">
       1) Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
      <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
      <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
      <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
      <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
       1) Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
      <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
      <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
      <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
      <br /> Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
    </div>
    <div id="cf2">
      test22222
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think this is what you are looking for..